# Regex pattern not inclusive of first character

Tags: regex, swift

I'm using this regex pattern: `@[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+` to match @usernames in strings.

Hey `@alex`, whatsup
`@brian` `@mary` cool photo

The text highlighted in `grey` is what is returned by the regex pattern, but I want it to return everything *after* the @ character. So what I actually want returned is:

Hey @`alex`, whatsup
@`brian` @`mary` cool photo

How should I change the pattern?

Comment: In what language/environment is this being executed? Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: @SeanBright I'm writing it in swift, but does the language matter? I thought the pattern is universal to regex. I am using a regex tester to confirm the matches.

Comment: It matters because how you would extract the username portion is different depending on the language.

Comment: You want to match starting with @, but not include @ in the result?  If so, try capturing sub-patterns or positive lookbehind.

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish the first one includes an '@', the second one doesn't include the '@'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a positive lookbehind, which entails asserting the following: I want to match `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+`, but only when there *is* ("positive") an `@` *before* it (hence, "lookbehind").

I don't know Swift regex syntax specifically, but most engines use `(?<=...)` for positive lookbehind. Hence:

```
(?<=@)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+
```

[Play with it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cP7pE5/1) if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a capture group? Place round brackets over the alpha-numeric characters after the `@`. Your match still include the `@` sign but you only capture the username:

```
let str = "Hey @alex, whatsup. @brian @mary cool photo"
let len = count(str) // if Swift 2.0 use: str.characters.count

let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "@([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)", options: nil, error:nil)
let matches = regex!.matchesInString(str, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0,len))
let nStr = str as NSString

for m in matches {
    let r = m.rangeAtIndex(1)
    println(nStr.substringWithRange(r)) // Use print in Swift 2.0
}
```

I don't have a Swift 2.0 compiler handy so make some changes if you are using Xcode 7 beta